# Wordpress site stuck in a redirect loop. Is the .htcaccess file causing it?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have been making some changes to a clients site and suddenly I can no longer access the admin end as it is getting stuck in a redirect loop. I have taken a look at the .htcaccess file and there seems to be a lot in there compared to what I have seen in the past. Could this be causing the issue? If not does anyone have any other suggestions? Thanks!

I did install a clear cache plugin to try and fix a separate issue, this is when it stopped working. I'm guessing this somehow caused the redirect loop but I am unsure how?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

## Gzip Compression ##
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 hour"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
Redirect 301 /finance/ /homeowners/finance/
Redirect 301 /registration/ /contact-us/
Redirect 301 /heating-installers/ /installers/
Redirect 301 /home-improvements/ /homeowners/
Redirect 301 /bathrooms-kitchens/ /homeowners/finance/
Redirect 301 /about-us-business/ /installers/about-us/
Redirect 301 /blog/ /installers/news/
Redirect 301 /contact/ /contact-us/
Redirect 301 /dt_logos/ /
Redirect 301 /gas-safety-week-2016/ /installers/news/
Redirect 301 /approved-trader/ /installers/
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/offers/ /installers/benefits/
Redirect 301 /consumer-faq/ /homeowners/
Redirect 301 /tradehelp-advance/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_logos/ideal/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_logos/logo03/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_logos/fernox/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_logos_category/partner/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_testimonials_category/installers/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_testimonials_category/customer/ /
Redirect 301 /thank-interest/ /
Redirect 301 /tradehelp-go-with-the-flow/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_logos/vokera/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_testimonials_category/installer2/ /
Redirect 301 /category/uncategorized/ /installers/news/
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/page/2/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/seo-optimised/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_logos/gas-safe/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_logos/midland-energy/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_logos/neil-shacklocks/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/qualified-tradesmen/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/member-handbook/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_logos/glow-worm/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/employee-documents/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/website-widgets/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/business-support/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/customizible-design/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/provide-finance/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_logos_category/color-logos/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_logos/page/2/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_testimonials_category/home-improve/ /
Redirect 301 category/gas-safe/ /installers/news/
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/heating-installers-2/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/home-improvements-2/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/kitchens-bathrooms-2/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_testimonials/total-maintenance-systems/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_testimonials/liverpool-boiler-repairs/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_testimonials/01-diana-red/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_testimonials_category/testimonials-category-01/ /
Redirect 301 /project/portfolio-post-with-video/ /
Redirect 301 /project-category/projects-category-1/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/top-deals-products-services/ /
Redirect 301 /project/portfolio-post-with-footer/ /
Redirect 301 /project-category/projects-category-3/ /
Redirect 301 /project/portfolio-post-with-gallery/ /
Redirect 301 /project-category/projects-category-2/ /
Redirect 301 /project/portfolio-post-with-fullwidth-gallery/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_testimonials/shaun-palmer-armistead-energy-solutions/ /
Redirect 301 /dt_benefits/easy-to-use-visual-layout-builder/ /
Redirect 301 /project/portfolio-post-with-fullwidth-image-list/ /
Redirect 301 /project/portfolio-post-with-fullwidth-gallery-2/ /
Redirect 301 /ideal-boilers-gives-us-a-vote-of-approval/ /installers/news/
Redirect 301 /project/portfolio-post-with-media-content-hidden-on-post-page/ /*
```

Comment: I had same issue that I found related to cache, please clear any cache and disable cache plugin. When you access to admin panel you can check queries with query monitor plugin and debug them.

Comment: as a start, you can first backup(rename) current .htaccess file and replace it with the WordPress default .htacess file(https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/). check whether you can access the back end: to make sure if it happens due to an issue with .htaccess file. if the issue still occurs. then you may need to rename the plugin you used recently to disable it(you need FTP access or access file manager via Cpanel or your host manager environment to this). and check whether the issue still there.